# How to make a pandas data frame with columns and headers for those columns

Tags: pandas

How to make a pandas data frame with columns and  headers for those columns

like the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if your read that as dataframe (df) and you only want the desired columns u should use:

```
df1 = df[['Aalborg Temp', 'Pressure', 'Windspeed', 'WindDir']]
```

by index u can try:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:5]
```